# About file operation in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, vfs

I have a question about the how the file_operations in the struct file is defined in linux kernel

[`vfs_read()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=3.1;a=arm#L348) calls

```
ret = file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);
```

I know this read is a function pointer, which is defined in some driver code, but is there a way to find where it is actually defined?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653100/struct-file-in-linux-driver

Comment: It depends on the filesystem type that the file is on.

Comment: It "is function pointer, which *points to a function that* is defined in some driver code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFS is "virtual file system". It is an abstraction over the underlying file system details, which of course differ greatly.

`f_op` is a set of `file_operations` that depend on which file system `file` is using.

For example, look at [`ext2_file_operations`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext2/file.c?v=3.1;a=arm#L63), where the ext2 filesystem exposes to the kernel which functions to use for its file operations.

If you want to see more, look for references to [`struct file_operations`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.1;a=arm;i=file_operations) in the `fs/` directory.

Comment: thanks. I found it. it is defined here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c?v=3.1;a=arm#L322